# Android Recycler View Item Layout Problem

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm designing an app in Android Studio. In the preview it looks like I want but when building the application there is a LinearLayout that contains two TextViews that looks smaller and I do not understand why

This is the Recycler View Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/friend_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:src="@drawable/head" />

        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="Guillermo Rodriguez" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friend_position"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="delantero"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks: https://photos.app.goo.gl/BgNQhgpNKbgEGCCR6 and I need to the text fill the entirety width

I expect to see both TextView until the end of the screen but they end before the middle. Any ideas?

Comment: @fitonga your internal LinearLayout has layout_width of 600dp, if your screen is wider, then it just has limited space. Why don't you use match_parent for that if you want it to be screen-wide?

Comment: @Peregreen I copied that wrong. Yes, there it goes match_parent but it happens the same. I put a number to test it but it didn't work. Any other idea?

Comment: @fitonga if this layout is for item inside of RecyclerView, it also matters how you inflate it. If you don't provide parent into inflating for onCreateViewHolder, then it won't be able to inflate root LayoutParams and will exchange your match_parent with wrap_content that could potentially affect internal LinearLayout. Could you post the code of inflating the item?

Comment: @Peregreen this is the method onCreateViewHolder. What do you think? Do you need any other?
    Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_invite_friend, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

Comment: @fitonga hm, interesting, it looks fine. Very strange, I would recommend to use the Layout Inspector and check what real layout parameters you have in your view. It's a very handy tool for this kind of investigations:
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Comment: Believe me , if you used ConstraintLayout , your life would be easier with this. I was having similar weir issues with LinearLayout. Looking at your code everything looks normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! Someone configured it whit GridLayoutManager and it had to be with LinearLayoutManager.. I changed it and it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you must want the two TextViews to fill the entirety of the height, is that it?

In that case, in both your TextViews, change your `layout_height` attribute to `0dp` and add `android:layout_weigth=0.5` to them. This will make them fill the entire height of your LinearLayout, whichever height that might be, and they will be dividing the space right in the middle.

Comment: No, I want the both thext view to fill the entirety of the width!
What is happening to me is that if one of the text is "delantero" it appears: "delan" and down "tero" , and that happens with both texts, there is a point where it separets it and cut it I don't know Why

Comment: This is how it looks: photos.app.goo.gl/BgNQhgpNKbgEGCCR6 and I need to the text fill the entirety width

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you utilize `LinearLayout`'s weight attribute. set your root `LinearLayout`'s to `match_parent`. and your nested `LinearLayout` and both `TextView`'s `layout_height` to `0dp` and their `weight` to 1
here's the edited code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/friend_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
android:layout_width="44dp"
android:layout_height="44dp"
android:src="@drawable/head" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="Guillermo Rodriguez" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/friend_position"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="delantero"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @fitonga sorry, my bad, I missplaced the nested LinearLayout's width and height. I have Edited my answer. Try the new code and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Now i have the same mistake than at first time

Comment: @fitonga can you upload an screenshot of your inflated layout ? and explain in more details how exactly you expect it to behave ?

Comment: This is how it looks: https://photos.app.goo.gl/BgNQhgpNKbgEGCCR6 and I need to the text fill the entirety width

Comment: I took a look at your picture and made some changes to the code, try this, let me know how it works, i changed the width and height of TextViews.

Comment: I am watching it with the layout inspector and i realised that the problem is the LinearLayour like you can see hear: https://photos.app.goo.gl/bB3jFJqSHmvGSHfR7 . Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: @fitonga i'll take a look at it right now and let you know

Comment: It's the same, I don't know where is the problem but I think maybe it's not in this .xml... In the preview that LinearLayout seams to be fine but in the inspector it looks wrong like in the reality, like in the photo i uploaded

Comment: @fitonga I had similar inflation problems with LinearLayout before, try changing the friend_layout (root LinearLayout) to RelativeLayout and see how it goes, let me know.

Comment: @fitonga by the way, check which orientation you are using for the linear layout manager of your RecyclerView

Comment: It didn't work with RelativeLayout neither.. Where is the Linear Layout manager orientation?

Comment: @fitonga upload the RelativeLayout you used, and also the LinearLayoutManager Code. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_invite_friend, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

Comment: @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = holder.friendLayout.getLayoutParams();
        if (lp instanceof FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
            FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams flexboxLp = (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams)
                    holder.friendLayout.getLayoutParams();
            flexboxLp.setFlexGrow(1.0f);
        }

Comment: if (selectedPlayersGlobal.contains(friends.get(position).id)) {
            selections.put(position, true);
        }
        holder.update(friends.get(position), position);
    }

Comment: For the relative layout i just change "LinearLayout" for "RelativeLAyout"

Comment: @fitonga Have you tried setting layoutInflater.inflate() 's  attachToRoot to true ?

Comment: @fitonga when you changed the LinearLayout to RelativeLayout, was the result exactly the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your `RecycleView` has the proper width set (e.g. `match_parent`) and it can stretch to the whole width. Could you provide the xml code with the `RecycleView`?

Answer (score 0):

i think you set the recyclerview to specific width. try to cahngethe width into match parent.
I recommend to user constraintlayout to avoid nested viewgroup. like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/friend_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:src="@drawable/patient"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="Guillermo Rodriguez"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_picture"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/friend_position"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="delantero"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_picture"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"/>
```